# Rego - Looping through a list of lists to check if they match given parameters

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

We currently can control which Kubernetes services of type "LoadBalancer" can be created.

`ConstraintTemplate`

```yaml
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: K8sMetalLBServicesGK
      validation:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          properties:
            allowedLBServices:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package k8smetallbservicesgk

        # Deny not whitelisted Service LB names
        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          is_not_getting_deleted
          is_type_loadbalancer
          svc := input.review.object.metadata.name
          satisfied := [good | pattern := input.parameters.allowedLBServices[_] ; good = glob.match(pattern, [], svc)]
          not any(satisfied)
          msg := sprintf("%v" service creation was denied by GateKeeper,[svc])
        }
        
        is_not_getting_deleted() = true {
          input.review.operation != "DELETE"
          not input.review.object.metadata.deletionTimestamp
        }

        is_type_loadbalancer() = true {
          input.review.object.spec.type == "LoadBalancer"
        }
```

`Constraint`

```yaml
spec:
  match:
    excludedNamespaces: ["*-system"]
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: ["*"]
        kinds: ["Service"]
  parameters:
    allowedLBServices:
      - pakalu
```

We would like to extend this by controlling which service of type "LoadBalancer" can be created per namespace. For that, we would need to change the validation in the template and the rule logic. So `constraint` could look similar to this, if we want to allow services named "pakalu" and "papito" in namespace "ham", and allow services named "pakalu" and "foo" in namespace "spam".

```yaml
spec:
  match:
    excludedNamespaces: ["*-system"]
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: ["*"]
        kinds: ["Service"]
  parameters:
    allowedLBServices:
      - ham:
          - pakalu
          - papito
      - spam:
          - pakalu
          - foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the constraint template to expect an object for `allowedLBServices`, and modify the policy to work with that:

```yaml
apiVersion: templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1
kind: ConstraintTemplate
metadata:
  name: k8smetallbservicesgk
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: K8sMetalLBServicesGK
      validation:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            allowedLBServices:
              type: object

  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package k8smetallbservicesgk

        # Deny not whitelisted Service LB names
        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          is_not_getting_deleted
          is_type_loadbalancer
          not allowed_in_namespace

          msg := sprintf("%v service creation was denied by GateKeeper", [input.review.object.metadata.name])
        }

        allowed_in_namespace {
          namespace := input.review.object.metadata.namespace
          pattern := input.parameters.allowedLBServices[namespace][_]
          glob.match(pattern, [], input.review.object.metadata.name)
        }

        is_not_getting_deleted {
          input.review.operation != "DELETE"
          not input.review.object.metadata.deletionTimestamp
        }

        is_type_loadbalancer {
          input.review.object.spec.type == "LoadBalancer"
        }
```

And update the constraint to use an object as well:

```yaml
apiVersion: constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: K8sMetalLBServicesGK
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  match:
    excludedNamespaces: ["*-system"]
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: ["*"]
        kinds: ["Service"]
  parameters:
    allowedLBServices:
      foo:
        - pakalu
```

Nit: I'd use rules over functions, unless you want to provide arguments.

Comment: I get this warning while applying the constraint after the new constraintTemplate is created: "The K8sMetalLBServicesGK "metallb-services" is invalid: spec.parameters.allowedLBServices: Invalid value: "object": spec.parameters.allowedLBServices in body must be of type array: "object"" I was getting something similar when trying to use nested arrays. Would you know why that is?

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to update the constraint to use an object for parameters too. I've updated the answer to provide that.